# Computation Cost of float Sizes

Tags: c++, c, types, floating-point

Is there any difference between the computation of small floats - that are close to 0 - and big floats - that are far from 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what kind of computation you are talking about. Adding two numbers together is likely to take the same length of time regardless of the magnitude of the number.  In the case of division, the size of the operand can make a difference - for instance, see [Intel reference manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf) page C.34:

If you try compiling the following code, you can see this in action:

```
// Compile with -O0 to avoid optimising out loop!
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <limits>

void test(float a, float b)
{
        struct timeval start, end;
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        for (size_t i=0; i<500000; ++i)
        {
                float result = a/b;
        }
        gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
        long  seconds, useconds; 
        seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
        useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
        double ms = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0); 
        std::cout  << a << "/" << b << " takes " << ms << "ms" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
        test(1,2);
        test(0.0005,1.0e+35);
}
```

Gives the following output for me

> 1/2 takes 1.032ms
>
> 0.0005/1e+35 takes 32.287ms

Comment: You need to make sure you turn off the optimizer for these test, they can actually in some instances optimize the code completely out.

Comment: Yes, this is important! I had put a comment in the code to this effect, but it is worth restating...

Comment: Not only can an optimizer remove the line, but a less aggressive one could also turn it into a multiplication (calculate `1/b` once, multiply by that 500.000 times)

Comment: Dividing something by two is typically a fast operation. The interesting question is if 'small'/2 is as fast as 'large'/2.

Comment: The two example divisions I used here were fairly arbitrary - if you test the division of a large range of numerators and denominators, you'll find most divisions run at about the same speed. Dividing enormous numbers by tiny numbers, or tiny numbers by enormous numbers will be slower. For integer division it is a different story, the speed depends on the size of the result.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand how processors work, there should be absolutely no difference at all

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on the platform that is used to compute the floating-point numbers. In general, there should be little or no difference. Internally, a floating-point number is represented using a normalized mantissa (a value between 0.5 and 1.0), a sign, and an exponent. The difference between a small and a large number is the value of the exponent.

Having said that, there is a notable exception. Really small floating-point numbers, so called *subnormal numbers* or *denormalized numbers* are represented differently, and some FPU:s do not have support for them. In that case, they escape to software to perform the calculations, which is really slow. Concretely, this is a problem in audio software where a sound can ring-off down to something which can't be heard, but once it is small enough, it will make the calculation slow down significantly.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no difference at all (ignoring precision issues). Floating point numbers always represent a number using a sign, fraction and exponent. There can't be any difference depending on its "size" and using some kind of integer replacement in case of small numbers or integer numbers wouldn't make any sense (just cause additional overhead) - to calculate you'd have to convert them again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no difference when those numbers can sit in a same datatype.